# JQuery code for removing class on page load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, removeclass

I am trying to remove a class from my HTML on page load. Class is called `wnDash` and it is inside `gamePage` class. I tried with this code below, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        var myAttr = $('gamePage').attr('wnDash');
        if (typeof myAttr !== 'undefined' && myAttr !== false) {
            $('gamePage').removeAttr('wnDash');
        }
    }, 250);
});
```

```
<div class='gamePage'>
    <p>
        <span class='balls' title='5'>5</span>
        <span class='wnDash'>-</span>
        <span class='balls' title='39'>39</span>
        <span class='wnDash'>-</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are removing an attribute not class `$('gamePage').removeClass('wnDash');` - Also the selector `gamePage` is not correct... what is it a class or id

Comment: There's several problems as @ArunPJohny has stated. If you could edit your question to include the HTML we can show you exactly how you need to amend your code.

Comment: Also using a timer may not be the correct solution as we won't be able to predict how long the system might take to execute the script that is adding the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `dot` for class. Use `hasClass()` for check if exsist

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
           $.each($('.gamePage').find(".wnDash"),function(){
            var text = $(this).text();
            $(this).text(text.replace("-","")) 
           })
    });
```

**Snippet UPDATE**

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
       $.each($('.gamePage').find(".wnDash"),function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace("-","")) 
       })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='gamePage'>
    <p>
        <span class='balls' title='5'>5</span>
        <span class='wnDash'>-</span>
        <span class='balls' title='39'>39</span>
        <span class='wnDash'>-</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still not working, it still shows on the screen.

Comment: What you want exacly? Because this code correct clear the class named "wnDash"

Comment: I want to remove this - from html, I made a mistake, I need this -,not the class removed. Is there any way to do this?